# sort a nested list of dicts by key in python

Tags: python, list

Below is an example nested list of dictionaries.  I want to order the lists by the number of points that Charlie has.

```
l = [[{'Name': 'Alice',   'Age': 40, 'Point': 80},
      {'Name': 'Bob',     'Age': 20             },
      {'Name': 'Charlie', 'Age': 30, 'Point': 10}],
     [{'Name': 'Alice',   'Age': 40, 'Point': 80},
      {'Name': 'Bob',     'Age': 20             },
      {'Name': 'Charlie', 'Age': 30, 'Point': 30}],
     [{'Name': 'Alice',   'Age': 40, 'Point': 80},
      {'Name': 'Bob',     'Age': 20             },
      {'Name': 'Charlie', 'Age': 30, 'Point': 20}]]
```

The output should look like this.

```
l = [[{'Name': 'Alice',   'Age': 40, 'Point': 80},
      {'Name': 'Bob',     'Age': 20             },
      {'Name': 'Charlie', 'Age': 30, 'Point': 10}],
     [{'Name': 'Alice',   'Age': 40, 'Point': 80},
      {'Name': 'Bob',     'Age': 20             },
      {'Name': 'Charlie', 'Age': 30, 'Point': 20}],
     [{'Name': 'Alice',   'Age': 40, 'Point': 80},
      {'Name': 'Bob',     'Age': 20             },
      {'Name': 'Charlie', 'Age': 30, 'Point': 30}]]
```

I think I should be able to use sorted() with the right arguments, but I'm not sure what the syntax would be.

```
sorted(l, key=lambda x: x[ ????? ])
```

Charlie is always the third dict in the sublists.

Comment: If Charlie always the third item in the sublists?

Comment: @mozway yes he is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Charlie is always third, you could use this:

```
sorted(l, key=lambda x: x[2]['Point'])
```

Otherwise, you'd want to use a helper function:

```
def get_charlie_points(lst):
    for item in lst:
        if item['Name'] == 'Charlie':
            return item['Point']
    return 0  # Replace this with the number you want if there is no Charlie, or raise an exception

sorted(l, key=get_charlie_points)
```

Comment: As you'll note in other answers, a generator expression combined with `next` would entirely eliminate your loop and conditional. `return next((d['Point'] for d in lst if d['Name'] == 'Charlie'), 0)`. The second argument to `next` also handles the default of `0`.

Comment: It is _possible_ to do that, but I prefer to write it like this, so it is more easily readable and maintainable. `x[2]['Point']` is about the most complex expression I'd put in a lambda.

Answer (score 3):

Use a lambda to search for Charlie's point in the nested lists:

```
l.sort(key=lambda lst: next(d.get('Point', 0) for d in lst if d.get('Name')=='Charlie'))
print(l)
```

If you want a new list:

```
out = sorted(l, key=lambda lst: next(d.get('Point', 0) for d in lst if d.get('Name')=='Charlie'))
```

Output:

```
[[{'Name': 'Alice', 'Age': 40, 'Point': 80},
  {'Name': 'Bob', 'Age': 20},
  {'Name': 'Charlie', 'Age': 30, 'Point': 10}],
 [{'Name': 'Alice', 'Age': 40, 'Point': 80},
  {'Name': 'Bob', 'Age': 20},
  {'Name': 'Charlie', 'Age': 30, 'Point': 20}],
 [{'Name': 'Alice', 'Age': 40, 'Point': 80},
  {'Name': 'Bob', 'Age': 20},
  {'Name': 'Charlie', 'Age': 30, 'Point': 30}]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Very similar to @enke's answer, but using `next` to provide the default `0`, rather than the `get` method.

```
s = sorted(l, key=lambda lst: next((d['Point'] for d in lst if d['Name'] == 'Charlie'), 0))
```

Answer (score 0):

If Charlie is always third, keep it simple, use:

```
out = sorted(l, key=lambda x:x[2].get('Point', float('inf')))
```

*NB. I used a default value of infinite if Charlie has no points, to push it to the end.*

Output:

```
[[{'Name': 'Alice', 'Age': 40, 'Point': 80},
  {'Name': 'Bob', 'Age': 20},
  {'Name': 'Charlie', 'Age': 30, 'Point': 10}],
 [{'Name': 'Alice', 'Age': 40, 'Point': 80},
  {'Name': 'Bob', 'Age': 20},
  {'Name': 'Charlie', 'Age': 30, 'Point': 20}],
 [{'Name': 'Alice', 'Age': 40, 'Point': 80},
  {'Name': 'Bob', 'Age': 20},
  {'Name': 'Charlie', 'Age': 30, 'Point': 30}]]
```

Comment: This is not a good solution because it assumes that the `Charlie` entry is always located on index `2`.

Comment: @Mario this is the case, see OP comments to the question. So trying to find the key when you know where it is would be a waste of resources ;)

Comment: Touché! Fair enough

Comment: @Mario that said, if you want to search for the key, better use an approach like that of enke, to stop searching on the first match. ;)